# How do I start a Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, windows, composer-php, laragon

I cannot start my Laravel application.

I have installed Composer and it's properly on my PHP file. I tried going with using a simple XAMPP stack and loading Laravel onto that manually but I couldn't get it to work.

I have now found **Laragon** which automates the process using WAMP.

The problem I am facing is that either way I go about doing this I keep getting this error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     Composer could not find the config file: %user%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
>   To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

I get this error each time I run the command:

```
composer  create-project laravel/laravel appName --prefer-dist
```

and

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel appName
```

I am just trying to create the project, after that I am golden but I cannot seem to find out what to do anywhere. Or at least not my problem I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're on Windows and somewhere along the line, your path to the composer vendor/bin folder is set as `%user%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`

According to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables) and the [Laravel installation guide](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation), that should be `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`. Either change that in your Windows Environment Variables path, or maybe reinstall composer using the executable to see if that solves your issue.

Make sure after changing the path, close down your command prompt or command line interface and start another for it to pick up the change.